# Is there a way to extract maximum flow graph from the given directed graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, max-flow

First of all, I want to extract the graph that gives me the max flow not the value of the max flow. I have searched the internet but couldn't find such an algorithm. Ford-Fulkerson algo also gives the value of the max flow but not the graph. One example is as follow:

[image]

and the max flow obtained from this graph is:

[image]

Is there any algorithm I am missing that does this? if so can anyone guide me through it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ford-Fulkerson does this; what's the problem? Also, if your question needs the images, post the images, not links to the images.

Comment: @Beta Yes, i know about ford-fulkerson algorithm. But I want the final residual graph I think that gives the path of the maximum flow through the graph. Ford-fulkerson only provides the value of the flow. Also sorry I can't post images in the post my level is low to be posting images.

Comment: The Ford-Fulkerson algorithm *generates* the residual graph. Some implementations simply return the maximum flow, but you can retain the graph too if you like. You have to understand the algorithm, not just copy-and-paste the code.

Comment: @Beta You may have forgotten, but users with <10 rep cannot post images directly, only links.